# Multiple SQL Dependencies on same table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldependency

I need to have two SQL dependencies on the same table as I have to monitor them for different reasons.

So I wrote the following two queries -

```
**SELECT [ID], [COLUMN1] FROM DBO.TABLENAME WHERE SOMECOLUMN = VAL1 ORDER BY ID**

**SELECT [ID], [COLUMN2] FROM DBO.TABLENAME WHERE SOMECOLUMN = VAL1 ORDER BY ID**
```

Earlier we were using only the first query, and second query was added later.
They are both used to create two separate dependencies.

But what I am observing is that when I update COLUMN2, I expect only callback registered with second query to get fired.  Instead BOTH callbacks ( callback registered with first query and the second query) are getting fired.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by dependencies in this context? Is this a trigger?

Comment: By dependencies in this context, I meant this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx

Comment: Why do you want two dependencies instead of one dependency that calls two functions? Would be much easier to control?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thanks for replying. Well the reason is that the actions to be taken on change of COLUMN1 and COLUMN2 are different. Hence, two dependencies calling two different functions.

Comment: Then I think you'll need to show some dependency set up/callback code, but I would still advice you to split them entirely, or be handled by the same controller. It's much easier to manage in my experience.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Ok. Will share some code. But can you tell me what is the reason for such behavior? Please correct me if I am wrong, but a SQL Dependency callback is triggered on change in result of query or change in the table itself?

Comment: I can't remember for sure (it's literally been years since I've worked with SQLDependency (found it too unstable)) - so this is off the top of my head - but I do seem to recall it was differentiating on the where clause and not on the selectable values. So perhaps add a 'group' identifier, and then modify your first query to look for "group = 1" and the second to look for "group = 2" ... something like that. But again - it's a long time past in the back of my mind (that's why I asked for code :))

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Sure thing! Will try out and let you know.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen So I changed my 2nd query to something like

SELECT [ID], [COLUMN2] FROM DBO.TABLENAME WHERE SOMECOLUMN = VAL1 AND COLUMN2 IN (// A COUPLE OF VALUES THAT IT CAN HAVE//)

But still same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differentiation between columns projected vs. columns updated has long been a problem with query notifications. Unfortunately things are as they are, so you will get false positives (notifications when nothing changed). See [Understanding When Query Notifications Occur](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188323%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Notice that SQL Server may produce a query notification in response to events that do not change the data, or in response to a change that does not actually affect the results of the query. For example, when an UPDATE statement changes one of the rows returned by the query, **the notification may fire even if the update to the row did not change the columns in the query results**.